# How could I render a Three.js scene with lighting and shading like this (attached)?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I've always found lighting and shading to be the most difficult part of WebGL / Three.js to get right – I feel like I'm making it up.

What combination of lighting and shading do you think I would need to achieve a similar look and feel to the following image? It's so soft and yet well-defined, whereas my attempts always come out harsh and haphazard.

[image]

Comment: Looks like flat shading + ambient occlusion, but I don't have much idea on how to achieve it with three.js

Comment: Well, the picture is rendered and therefore quite smooth. To get the triangulated look, you have to recalculate the vertex normals of your mesh(es). As you can see, they need to have the same direction as the face normal, so for every triangle, copy over the face normal into its 3 vertex normals. 
For the lighting, maybe try SSAO and some post processing to get the colors according to your reference image but there is no built-in way to get this smooth indirect illumination in three.js that i am aware of.

Comment: both comments are valid ; your ref uses a low poly model with Global Illumination ( Hundreds of thousands of lights rays contributing to the shading of the mesh ) which is not possible with THREE. 

so you need a low poly mesh with baked textures then the effectComposer can help you achieve the "instagramish" look. the built-in fog won't allow you to get the slight haze and, as it is baked, when your meshes move, you'll lose the shading interactions ; the space between the horses is darker because light can't reach it as much as their backs/heads this is AO (& SSAO won't work very well here).

Comment: If things are going to be static, you can bake the rendering and import the objects

Answer (score 1):

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shadowmap
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse

This examples use the same lightning effect, check out the Code.